# Ubuntu Customization Kit (UCK) for Ubuntu Mac version

Tags: boot, live-usb, mac, live-cd, uck

I am using UCK for creating custom ubuntu 14.04 ISO live-cds,
I then burn the ISO into usb-disk with YUMI or Universal USB Installer or uNetBootin or similar.

Booting on PCs it really works well.
Then i tried to boot on a Mac, following the steps here indicated
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-boot-a-linux-live-usb-stick-on-your-mac/

It boots ok, but suddenly Ubuntu uses to crash in a kind of "blue (black) screen" with a dump of memory and registers.

I think it is happening because the version of Ubuntu of customized and burned wasnt the "mac" version, am i right ?

may i be confident that the "mac" version of the Ubuntu is enough tested to be used in a live environment ? why does exists a "mac" version ? is out there a cross-platform version of ubuntu ? or may i easily add the required files for mac to make my pc-version of ubuntu mac compatible ?
if so, is there any tutorial about it ?

what about the 15.04 version ?

thank you very much

javier